# NSMatrix in ScrollView; origin settings are locked. Why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, scrollview, nsmatrix

I have an `NSMatrix`, embedded within a scroll view (using IB). It works great, using the `-sizeToCells` method after changing the number of rows/columns. But I would like to move the initial matrix inside the scrollview. IB grays out the X and Y settings. Why, and how would it be possible to change the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the `NSScrollView` or its `NSClipView` will always set the `documentView`'s origin to `(0,0)`.  (Might be in [`-[NSScrollView tile]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/tile)?)

Therefore, IB disables the origin settings because they will never be used.

If your app is working correctly, I wouldn't worry about what it looks like in IB.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. But what I need to do, is shift my matrix to the right and down, so I can place labels inside. I suppose that can be done if I manually design my `NSScrollView` and dump everything I need in there. (But the automatically working scroll bars are soooo handy....) Am I correct in assuming that the embedding can only result in a single control inside the scrollview?

Comment: `NSScrollView` can contain only one `NSView` as its `documentView`, yes. However, you can put as many subviews in the documentView as you like. You don't need to subclass `NSScrollView` or `NSClipView`, just make a subclass of `NSView` to be the `documentView`.